# I have problems with array in nesC(tinyOS)

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, nesc

I have problems to initialize the array in nesC.

When I code the line below, and build the project error appears shown below:

```
nx_uint16_t file[10];
```

The error:

[image]

In The Timer0.fired() function below, the array is initialized, as the part of the function:

```
 event void Timer0.fired(){
            //counter++;
            //call Leds.set(counter);

        printf("\nTelosb mote Timer start.");
        printfflush();
        if (!busy) {
            BlinkToRadioMsg* btrpkt = (BlinkToRadioMsg*)(call Packet.getPayload(&pkt, sizeof
            (BlinkToRadioMsg)));
            printf("\nTelosb mote Timer efter busy.");

        printfflush();


            call Leds.led0On();

            btrpkt->nodeid = 15;
            btrpkt->counter = counter;
            //btrpkt->hop = 1;
            btrpkt->value = 2;


            nx_uint16_t file[10];
            nx_uint8_t j;

            for ( j = 0;j<30;j++)
                {

                    int ra = (rand()+1) % 10;
                    file[j]=ra;
                    //printf("The array : %d ", file[j]);
                    //printfflush();

                }



        if (call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &pkt, sizeof(BlinkToRadioMsg)) == SUCCESS) {
            busy = TRUE;

        }
        }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile error when creating packet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200635/compile-error-when-creating-packet)

Comment: As per the link, you seem to have to declare variables outside of the function or at the start of the function.

Comment: I agree with @PeterM, without knowing more about your compiler and the options it supports, the most likely cause is that it does not support declaring variables in the middle of the function.